# Position of the key "__type" in a JSON WCF service being consumed on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to consume a webservice made by my client on the iPhone. It was used, from what they told me, using WCF. The problem is that I need to send a bunch of parameters to a method, and one of them is a key called "__type", that needs to be the first key on the dictionary. I tried to argue that Dictionaries, by definition, do not guarantee the order of the keys, but the insist that it is necessary that this specific key is the first in the dictionary.
From what I gathered, this property is what they call a type hint, and it really has to be the first property on the dictionary.

Is there any way for me to do this on the iPhone?

Comment: Hello! Did you find a way how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a little late, but I would recommend [SBJson framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) for this.

By setting the sortKeys property on SBJsonwriter, your keys will be sorted alphabetically. 
Presumably your keys have names that will make __type the first key in the sorted JSON.

```
NSDictionary *unsortedDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                                    initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"Doe", @"lastName",
                                    @"Person", @"__type",
                                    @"John",@"firstName",
                                    nil];

SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
writer.sortKeys = YES;
NSLog(@"%@",[writer stringWithObject:unsortedDictionary]);
```

This will produce nicely sorted JSON:

```
{"__type": "Person","firstName": "John","lastName": "Doe"}
```

Comment: Thanks! just to update, with SBJson4, the sort resulted __type to be in the last object, you'll need to implement `writer.sortKeysComparator = ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) { return [obj2 compare:obj1]; };` to reverse the order so __type is first.